# NetBeans custom script

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I want to select one of more files in the NetBeans project navigator and it execute a single shell script, so if I selected `MyClass.php` and `MyOtherClass.php` it would run a script like (and show the output in the console):

```
myscript.sh /project/path/MyClass.php /project/path/MyOtherClass.php
```

Is this possible? I've tried searching google but there seems to be no functionality in NetBeans. This is because the support for PHPUnit in NetBeans is awful and I can't get it to find the test files at all, even if I let NetBeans create the PHPUnit files.